# Calling a data member's setter in its getter

Tags: java

This question is kind of linked to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900121/java-ensuring-the-data-members-are-set-after-object-gets-instantiated-or-assig) I asked in this forum.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish. I have the following class:

```
public class LoginPage
{
    // Class Data
    private HtmlForm loginForm;

    // Calling the constructor of the parent class
    public LoginPage()
    {
        loginForm = null;
    }

    public void setLoginForm()
    {
        ...... logic to find the login form ........
    }

    public HtmlForm getLoginForm()
    {
        return loginForm;
    }

    ...... other login related methods ........
}
```

**I want to ensure that every time a getLoginForm() method is called it should not return null.** One way to do this is to ensure setLoginForm() is called before the getLoginForm() method is called.

**Can i call the setter of a data member within its getter method.** In this case:

```
    public HtmlForm getLoginForm()
    {
        setLoginForm()
        return loginForm;
    }
```

I have never seen some thing like this being practiced. **Is this valid ? What are the merits and demerits of doing this ?**

Appreciate your comments / suggestions !!!!

Comment: Why would it not be valid? You are calling a method from within a method, normal in Java.

Comment: Usually setters take an argument, in your case it would be an `HtmlForm`. Your setter seems unneeded; its logic should probably be in the getter.

Comment: What is the reason, you are not initializing it in the constructor? If it's because of an expensive creation, I think the way you go is ok. But then I would make ´setLoginForm´ private, to avoid setting from outside.

Comment: And call `setLoginForm` `initLoginForm`. It is not a real setter.

Comment: @F.Böller yes it is an expensive creation. Hence i wanted to do that in a setter

Comment: @GriffeyDog I understand that usually setters do take an argument. In my case what ever i need , i get it once LoginPage is "assigned". The setters only look within the page to set individual data members.

Comment: @MohanBhargav I recommend that you rename your "setter" like others have suggested, e.g. initLoginForm(). OldCurmudgeon's answer looks good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual pattern for this would be something like:

```
public class LoginPage {

    // Class Data
    private HtmlForm loginForm;

    // Calling the constructor of the parent class
    public LoginPage() {
        loginForm = null;
    }

    // Normal setter - NB: Private - so I am in complete control.
    private void setLoginForm(HtmlForm loginForm) {
        this.loginForm = loginForm;
    }

    private void initialiseLoginForm() {
        if ( loginForm == null ) {
            // Build a loginForm and use the private setter to set it.
            // NB: In a multi-threaded environment you would normally use some kind of synchronization.
            HtmlForm newForm;
            // ...
            setLoginForm(newForm);
        }
    }

    // Normal getter
    public HtmlForm getLoginForm() {
        initialiseLoginForm();
        return loginForm;
    }

}
```

This creates the form late and disallows users from modifying it. Note that I have used the correct signature for a setter which is usually `setXxx(T it)`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it "valid"? Sure.

Is it a good idea? Hard to say–depends on the situation.

It's basically a "lazy" getter; if the object hasn't been initialized, make sure it is, then return it.

Unrelated but I'd argue the method is mis-named and should instead reflect something closer to what it's doing, e.g., `initLoginForm`, `findLoginForm`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is valid, and as far as if it's useful, it depends on the situation... it could be useful to save some memory resources but you should make a small yet possibly very efficient change... (see bellow)

> I want to ensure that every time a getLoginForm() method is called it should not return null.

First of all, you should probably rename the `setLoginForm()` method to something like `initLoginForm()`. The reason is that `setLoginForm()` isn't really a setter and it serves to initialize the resources of the login form.

A setter would look like this:

```
    public void setLoginForm(HtmlForm loginForm) {
       this.loginForm = loginForm; // set the login form
    }
```

Right now, the way you have it is you call `setLoginForm()` each time you call `getLoginForm()` which is unnecessary. What you want is to instantiate the `LoginForm` **only if it is** `null` before returning it (this is called [**lazy initialization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)).

Lazy initializations means that we don't create objects until the first time we need them.
It is useful memory conservation technique because it refrains from creating certain resources until the resource is first needed -- freeing valuable memory space. It is especially useful when object initialization is expensive.

So you make your getter be "lazy":

```
    public HtmlForm getLoginForm() {
        if(loginForm == null) { //first call to this method.
            loginForm = new HtmlForm();
        }
        return loginForm;
    }
```

The `== null` check should be the changed to however in your system design you would check "**Is loginForm instantiated**".

I guess more general, your code could look like:

```
    public HtmlForm getLoginForm() {
        if(!isLoginFormInitialized()) { //initialize the login form if it isn't initialized
            initLoginForm();
        }
        return loginForm;
    }
```

This way you are still making sure your `loginForm` is initialized but you are not wasting resources by recreating it each time.

**NOTE:** Since you didn't provide any specifications of your underlying system and how you setup the login form, do you allow `null` values, what design patterns you might be using etc. I just provided a general answer to what seems like you are asking. Hopefully it helps :)

Comment: In general I agree, but without knowing anything about the system in question, it's a stretch to claim the logic is wrong as written--nullness may not be appropriate criteria.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes you are correct, it seems to me that this is what he wanted based on his code. Since he didn't mention anything about the underlying system that pretty much makes his question general and thus I thought it is sufficient to provide a general answer :)

Answer (score 0):

sure you could do it, but its not a goog idea.

in general, a nice Application would be designed under the **MVC** Concept:

**MVC:** Model-View-Controller

**Model**: your Objects like User(attributes and Getter + Setter), Product, Category,...etc. 
getter and Setters shouldn't have any Logic, just setting or getting values.

**View**: your GUI

**Controller**: ManagedBeans that do logics, calculating, DataBase, ....etc.

if you want to check AND / OR init any values, then do this in the Controller not in the Model!

Usually, a setter Method needs a paramater to set the value:

```
public void setData(DataType data ){
   this.data = data;
}
```